# Javascript function to return value between threshold of array objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got the following `scores` object in JavaScript:

```
[
  {
    "id":37,
    "title":"Over achieving",
    "description":"Exceeding expectations",
    "threshold":10,
  },
  {
    "id":36,
    "title":"Achieving",
    "description":"Achieving expectations",
    "threshold":6,
  },
  {
    "id":35,
    "title":"Under achieving",
    "description":"Not achieving expectations",
    "threshold":3,
  }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a method that will return the score object based on a value determined by the score threshold.

I've tried the following but it only returns the score if the value is equal to the score threshold, not between it.

```
scores.find(o => o.threshold <= progress && o.threshold >= progress)
```

So the scenario is, a person has a progress `value` of 5, I'd like the method to return the score array item with the `id` of 35 because 5 is between 3 and 6. Similarly, if the progress `value` is 7 then I'd like the method to return the score array item with the `id` of 36 because 7 is between 6 and 10.

I'm sure I'm not far off.

Comment: The question is not clear what is the expected output and what is o.threshold?

Comment: Yea.  how do you expect to get a value between two others when you only have one threshold value?

Comment: _based on a value determined by the score threshold._   And whats the logic behind this threshold?

Comment: The scenario is someone has a progress `value` of 5, I would therefore expect the score `id` of 35 to be returned because 5 is between the thresholds of 3 and 6. I hope this helps.

At the moment what I have only returns a score array if the `value` equals the `threshold`

Comment: @TiagoVitorino - the logic behind threshold is `scores` is a collection of items and each item will contain a `threshold` number that is used to check if a progress `value` sits within (or between) a score item. The `scores` object can be configured to contain many items, and each item may have their own `threshold`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort your `scores` array in reverse order first, you can then adjust your callback to find the first score with `threshold` that's merely less than the `progress`.

```js
// doing it this way solely to keep it on a single line.
const scores = JSON.parse('[{"id":37,"title":"Over achieving","description":"Exceeding expectations","threshold":10},{"id":36,"title":"Achieving","description":"Achieving expectations","threshold":6},{"id":35,"title":"Under achieving","description":"Not achieving expectations","threshold":3}]');

const getScore = (progress) => scores.sort((a, b) => b.threshold - a.threshold).find(score => score.threshold <= progress);

const showScore = (progress) => {
    const lowestThreshold = scores.sort((a, b) => a.threshold - b.threshold)[0];
    const score = getScore(progress) || lowestThreshold;
    console.log(`${progress} returns`, score.id);
};

const allValues = [...Array(15).keys()].map(showScore);
```

Comment: Hey @pete - this is real close, thanks. The only issue is where there's a `value` that is less than the lowest `threshold` in the collection of `scores` - the code returns `undefined`. Is there any way to get it to return the `id` of the lowest `threshold` if this is the case?

Comment: @NeilMerton sure. just default the `score` in the `showScore` function to be the score object with the lowest threshold. updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the *first item* in the array whose *threshold is below or equal to the progress*. The expression

```
scores.find(o => o.threshold <= progress)
```

will do that.

Comment: @Ivan Why, what is the desired result? Is 10 between 6 and 10, or is it between 10 and Infinity?

Comment: My answer was incorrect yours seemed incorrect too but actually, it's not. OP wants the function to return `37` if progress is `10`. So he needs `<=` instead. +1

Answer (score 0):

Even if your `scores` array is **NOT** sorted by threshold.

```js
let progress = 5;
let scores = [{"id":37, "title":"Over achieving", "description":"Exceeding expectations", "threshold":10,}, {"id":36, "title":"Achieving", "description":"Achieving expectations", "threshold":6,}, {"id":35, "title":"Under achieving", "description":"Not achieving expectations", "threshold":3,}]

let item = scores.filter(o => (o.threshold <= progress)).reduce((acc, curr) =>  (curr.threshold >= acc.threshold)? curr: acc)

console.log(item);
console.log(item.id);
```

I hope this will help ;)